# How to link dynamic library "-li2c" with Cmake? (undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_write_byte_data`)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, shared-libraries, i2c

As I'm rather new to Cmake usage, I don't really know how to solve this problem. In my C++ code, I use functions from the Linux i2c library, as follows:

```
extern "C" {
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <i2c/smbus.h>
}
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

bool cpi2c_writeRegister(uint8_t address, uint8_t subAddress, uint8_t data) {
    return i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(address, subAddress, data) == 0;
}
```

I usually compile with Cmake using CMakeLists, but now it doesn't work since it states: `undefined reference to 'i2c_smbus_write_byte_data'`. I tried with G++ to link dynamically:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c main.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -o Main main.o -li2c
```

This worked well and there are no problems. The problem is I really need to compile with CMakeLists, so do you know a way how to achieve this? Cmake does not find the package by default (since it has no .config-file) and I don't know where the functions from `i2c/smbus.h` are defined.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, show(add to the question post) `CMakeLists.txt` script you use to build the project.

Comment: target_link_libraries [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/target_link_libraries.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, that solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [pkg-config](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) is generally preferred to link libraries that have a .pc file.

But as libi2c does not seem to install a .pc file you can use `target_link_libraries()` directly by providing the library name. For simplicity and portability use the "Plain library name" (see the [target_link_libraries documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)).

```
target_link_libraries(main i2c)
```

CMake will take care of expanding the plain library name to `-li2c`, `i2c.lib`, or whatever is suited to your build environment and operating system.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** add

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
  i2c
)
```

To your CMakeList.txt.

**Step 2:** Declare the headers as "C",

```
extern "C"
{
    #include<linux/i2c-dev.h>
    #include <i2c/smbus.h>
}
```

Because libi2c.so is a dynamic library compiled with GCC.

If you do not declare it explicitly, the g++ will generate different function names in the symbol table thus the ld command cannot find any match in the i2c library.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is, you can use the command target_link_libraries() after creating the executable. You have to provide the name of the object and a path to the .so-file (usually found in /usr/lib). In my case, that would be:

```
target_link_libraries(main, "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libi2c.so")
```

Comment: I don't think you want the comma after main.

Comment: Absolute paths in CMakeLists.txt are bad.