# RaspberryPi: undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read*' functions in C userspace

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, linker, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to compile a userspace C sourcefile which uses `i2c_smbus_read_*` and `i2c_smbus_write_*` functions in a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with kernel `5.10.63-v7+`. It should be possible, according to [this Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/dev-interface.html) document. I already installed `libi2c-dev`.

If I use:

```
#include <linux/i2c.h> 
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h> 
#include <i2c/smbus.h>
```

and I run `gcc myfile.c -o myfile`, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWkqsK.o: in function `i2c_read':
myfile.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWkqsK.o: in function `i2c_write':
myfile.c:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_write_block_data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which could it be the problem?

---

Note that these functions are present in my `/usr/include/i2c/smbus.h`:

```
...
extern __s32 i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(int file, __u8 command);
extern __s32 i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(int file, __u8 command, __u8 value);
extern __s32 i2c_smbus_read_word_data(int file, __u8 command);
...
```

Comment: `extern "C"` is a C++ construct. And you need to link in the appropriate i2c library.

Comment: @DevSolar Ok, then it is unuseful in this case. I had this suspect.

Comment: The problem with the first error is that you don't link with the right libraries of object files. The problem with the second error is that you use a C++ construct in a C source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree you don't need `extern "C"`in a C program. Check your headers and see if your header defines the function as `inline` or not. If it only declares it, you need to find out which library is the function defined in and link the library in your program.

**Edit:** I see you already updated the question. In this case you need to link the i2c library similar to what they do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890499/how-to-link-dynamic-library-li2c-with-cmake-undefined-reference-to-i2c-smb). Just add a parameter to your gcc command: `-li2c`.

Comment: Thank you so much, `-li2c` solved the issue.